# PHP Array into JS Array

Tags: php, arrays

Admittedly, my understanding of arrays is junior at best (although before this I thought I had them figured out).

Essentially, I am trying to convert a PHP array to a JS array.  The purpose for this is that ultimately I'd like to create a graph/chart using jquery (I've tried using php charts, but they haven't worked for me to this point).

Long story short, every time I try and convert my PHP array to a JS array, the output is "null".  This may be due to my understanding of arrays...

```
//this query gets me the count of each type of variabletype

$sql = "SELECT variabletype, COUNT(variabletype) AS value_occurrence FROM variable GROUP BY variabletype ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC";
$vars_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

 while($vars = mysqli_fetch_array($vars_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {

//this is a sub-query that gets me how many of those records are considered "positive"
$times_positive_qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT variable.variabletype, COUNT(value.valueid) AS positive_occurrence FROM variable INNER JOIN value On variable.variableid=value.variableid WHERE variable.variabletype = '" .$vars['variabletype']. "' AND value.valuelift>0.00 AND value.valuesignificant=1 GROUP BY variable.variabletype ORDER BY positive_occurrence DESC");
$times_positive = mysqli_fetch_array($times_positive_qry, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$pos = $times_positive['positive_occurrence'];

}

//this is the code that is supposed to take my php array and turn it into JS array.
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
 $php_array = $pos;
 $js_array = json_encode($php_array);
 echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
 echo "</script>";
```

Again, my understanding of arrays are junior, but I think it may have to do with my use of $pos.  Is this not an array?  or am I missing the mark somewhere else?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: try a `var_dump` on `$pos` and see what the type is. That'll answer your question why it's returning null from `json_encode`

Comment: On a sidenote, you might want to read up on arrays in the [official PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), so your understanding of them increases :)

Comment: your `while` loop assigns a scalar value to `$pos`, so it's definitely not an array.  and i'd bet the code is not executed at all (`mysqli_fetch_array($vars_query, ...)` returns no rows), so `$pos` is not defined, and you've shot yourself in the foot with insufficient `error_reporting`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could explicitly declare $pos as an array like this:

```
$pos = array();
```

Inside the while loop, you can ensure that it's an array and that you don't lose data while iterating over the loop by using brackets like so:

```
$pos[] = $times_positive['positive_occurrence'];
```

That syntax automatically creates an indexed array. If you don't use that syntax, then the value of $pos will be only the value assigned on the final loop of the while statement.

Comment: I get the following error: "Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in /blah/blah/blah/filename.php.  I added `$pos[] = $times_positive['positive_occurrence'];` in my while loop.  Any thoughts here?

Comment: That probably means the $pos is declared with a value somewhere earlier in the code, so it's already a string variable. Make sure to add the explicit declaration $pos = array(); just before the while loop.

Comment: Great! Did you mean to accept the other answer though?

Answer (score 1):

You have this line:

```
$pos = $times_positive['positive_occurrence'];
```

It assignes a value to the variable `$pos`. The value you are assigning is probably not an array, but besides, you overwrite $pos every time in the loop.

So I think you meant to do this:

```
$pos[] = $times_positive['positive_occurrence'];
```

That will treat `$pos` as an array and appends every new value to the end of the array.

You may want to start your script by writing `$pos = array();`. That way, you make sure $pos already exists and is a valid (empty) array in case the query doesn't return any result.

Comment: I get the following error: "Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in /blah/blah/blah/filename.php. I added $pos[] = $times_positive['positive_occurrence']; in my while loop. Any thoughts here?

Comment: That means `$pos` was already a string before entering the loop. Maybe you've accidentally recycled the same variable name? If you add `$pos = array();` before the loop, you should be fine, although for readability it's better to use a more descriptive variable name, and not to use the same name for two different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

this might be the solution you want.

1. before while loop just declare $pos = array();
2. and in the while loop use $pos as $pos[]

and your javascript looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
//this is just and example you can replace it with $pos[]
$php_array = array('abc','def','ghi');
?>
var js_array =<?php echo json_encode($php_array);?>;//do not add quotes to this line
alert(js_array[0]);
</script>
```